# What is "Pointer" in DM14 at J1939 CAN-bus standard?

Tags: can, protocol

What is "Pointer" in DM14 at J1939 CAN-bus standard? Can it be the memory **Address[DEC]**?

Comment: Hi, can I ask where you got this document? I'm not trying to pay to look at a spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pointer contains a value which is the address of memory to be used for the read or write operation.

Comment: So if I got the address of EEPROM memory 200, then I should write 200 to the Pointer? And the length is the lenght of the EEPROM memory value e.g. 2 bytes?

Comment: That would be my guess, yes.

Comment: Ok. I take that as an answer. J1939-21 is not an well explained protocol.